# java.lang.RuntimeException Android Studio

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception, android-studio-3.2

When I try to run my code, I got some trouble. In build console-log:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException

I tried to look at some solutions, but not work anymore. I down version of compileSdkVersion. cleans and re-build. But nothing change. Here my detail error log:

```
org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failure.
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException
at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)

Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitModule(ClassVisitor.java:148)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:731)
```

And, this my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xx.xx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled = true
    versionCode 86
    versionName "1.0.86"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndrtransformClassesWithDexBuilderForReleaseoidJUnitRunner"
    android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
implementation('com.omertron:themoviedbapi:4.2') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    exclude module: 'junit'
}
implementation files('libs/okhttp-3.8.1.jar')
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation files('libs/okio-1.13.0.jar')
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha06'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1-jre'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
implementation 'javax.mail:mail:1.5.0-b01'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'

implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.3@aar'
implementation 'io.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android:8.9.0'
implementation 'com.github.joielechong:countrycodepicker:2.1.5'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation files('libs/xxx.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

So, hope someone can help me. I spent a lot of time but still don't know how to fix it. Many thanks.

Comment: have you extended Application in your app?

Comment: @KaranMer what do you means ? I can't get it.

Comment: This stack trace is not very informative. Do you remember what you changed to trigger this error? If you use a VCS try to go back a few commits.

Comment: @AkiNoKo : Do you have any class in your app this is extending from Application class?

Comment: @KaranMer I think i got my trouble. wrong typo in build.gradle.

Comment: @Henry yea. lucky i had one backup. so, time to revert code